# If $G$ is group of nilpotency class 3 then $G'$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is group of nilpotency class 3 then we can say $G'$ is abelian group? This question is true? ($G'$ is derived of $G$.)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is a general fact that if $L_{i}(G)$ denotes the $i$-th term of the lower central series of a group $G,$ then $[L_{i}(G),L_{j}(G)] \leq L_{i+j}(G).$ If $G$ has nilpotency class $3,$ then $L_{4}(G) =1,$ and $G^{\prime} = L_{2}(G),$ so we find that $[G^{\prime},G^{\prime}] = 1$, ie $G^{\prime}$ is Abelian, for such a group.

Comment: very very thanks

Comment: @user149120 I first gave an answer but misunderstood your question and withdrew my answer.

Comment: that means this question in false ?